# Translating an English logic statement to a MatLab one

Tags: matlab, command, logic

Here is the promp: The statement if either of two conditions is met: either (1) R is true and Q is false or (2) P or R is true but not both. All other conditions are false.

I’m new to MatLab so what I tried was:
R & Q | xor(P,R)

I think I got the P and R part but I’m not sure about R and Q.  Does R must be true and Q must be false in order for 1 to be true ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So for example, if R is false and P is true then the whole statement is true right ?

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as follows:

```
(R & ~Q) | xor(P,R)
```

As you said, the second part of your statement is correct. But in the first one you have to check for `R = true` and `Q = false`. In Matlab, the `not` operator is performed using the tilde character `~` (reference [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html)). For more information about logical operators, read [this part](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html) of the official documentation.

Single logical operators are good for performing operation with logical variables, especially with indexing which is a very frequent operation to perform in Matlab. If you want to use these conditions into an if statements, you have to write them as follows:

```
if ((R && ~Q) || xor(P,R))
    % do something
end
```